# Java Generics - clearList implementation

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to write a simple method using generics. But I am getting compilation error saying

> The method remove() in the type `Iterator<T>` is not applicable for the arguments `(T)`"

Here is the code.

```
<T> void empty(List<T> list){       
    Iterator<T> itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        itr.remove(itr.next());//Error here
    }
}
```

Comment: `Iterator` only has `remove()`, not `remove(<T>)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Iterator#remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) doesn't receive any parameter. Remove the parameter from the method.

```
//advance the iterator
itr.next();
//remove the element
itr.remove();
```

If you're looking to remove a specific element of the list, then do a comparison first against the desired conditions, then remove the element:

```
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    T foo = itr.next();
    //do the comparison
    if ( ... ) { // using foo
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops !. No wonder why google search didn't get me the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator.remove()` takes no argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface Iterator<E>
```

The remove() doesn't take any parameter.

```
void remove():
```

Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next(). The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html